# Error with node packages after angular cli 1.5+ update

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

So I upgrade our app from angular 2 to angular 5, all seemed well until when I updated my cli version(which was of angular 2 before) to the latest currently 1.7.1

The problem is some of the npm packages are throwing error like this

```
some.directive.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format.
```

So it seems that the packages were incorrectly build, googling about it I found out that it was a bug in the angular/cli that was been fixed in the version 1.5 onwards.

https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced#148d

I tried by placing the respective ts files in the tsconfig.json, but it didn't work or maybe I was missing out on something.

What might be the solution to this, other than forking the package source and making a proper build(That's my worst case scenario)